# Infact of removing, Member from iOS developer program.

Tags: ios, iphone, ipa, iphone-developer-program

I developed an iPad Application for one of my client.

It was in-house application. They have Apple Enterprise License. So they invite me as a Admin. So I logged in to their portal and created a distribution certificate and in-house provisioning profile. Using that profile I build the project and created an .IPA file and sent it to the client to distribute among their users.

Now they are planing to delete me from iOS developer program. They are not going to do anything to certificate and provisioning profile I created in their portal. I want to confirm that my app is going to run even after they delete me from their account. I search the web but could not find a trusted source.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I did not get any response I checked it by myself. I created a admin using one of my client's Enterprise account. Then I created a certificate. Then I delete that admin. Then login to the portal using another admin using same machine. I was able to build app using that certificate. So It seems deleting admin account wont effect on the certificate.